# Detectar la versión de Android en Android-studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estoy desarrollando una app en la que debo lanzar distintas funcionalidades según la versión del android del usuario por problemas de compatibilidad, ya que estoy usando un webView que las versiones inferiores a 6.0 no parecen soportar correctamente. Por ello, me gustaría saber si hay algún método para devolver la versión de android del dispositivo en que se ejecuta la aplicación.

Answer (score 6):

Para obtener la version de android en un `String` puedes usar lo siguiente:

```
String version = Build.VERSION.RELEASE;
```

Eso devolvera la version tipo `4.4` `5.1`...

Si lo que quieres es usar un a funcion u otra dependiendo de la version, podrias usar algo como esto:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
    // versiones con android 6.0 o superior
} else{
    // para versiones anteriores a android 6.0
}
```

Answer (score 2):

La forma correcta de obtener la version del sistema operativo es:

```
int versionSDK = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
```

La version obtenida es [el nivel de la API](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html?hl=es-419#ApiLevels)

---

Al obtener la versión del SDK, puedes validar cierta funcionalidas, por ejemplo si deseas validar con respecto a la versión 6.0, [nivel de API 23 y versionCode M.](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html?hl=es-419#ApiLevels)

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
    //para versiones con android 6.0 o superior.
} else{
    //para versiones inferiores a android 6.0.
}
```

Comment: mmm -1 porque razón? La versión del OS esta relacionada a una constante numérica .